# wrapper bash script calls ksh script but hangs on a function

Tags: bash, shell, unix, ksh

I have a bash script

foo.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "start"
. /path/to/bar/bar.ksh
echo "after bar"

getoravariables $1
```

bar.ksh (purpose is to just set oracle variables):

```
#!/bin/ksh
echo "b4 getora"
getoravariables () {
echo "1"
if [ $# -ne 1 ]
then
echo "2"
        echo "Usage: getoravariables sid"
        exit 1
fi

grep -w ${1} ${ORATAB_LOC} | grep -v "#" | sed "s/:/ /g" | read SID ORAHOME ASK


if [ $? -ne 0 ]
then
        print "Error: Please enter a vaild SID and check the ${orafile} file for correct input"
        return 1
fi

ps -ef|grep pmon|grep ${SID} >> /dev/null

if [ $? -ne 0 ]
then
        print "Error: SID ${SID} does not seem to be started.  "
        return 2
fi

export ORACLE_SID=${SID}
export ORACLE_HOME="${ORAHOME}"
export ORAENV_ASK=NO

. $ORACLE_HOME/bin/oraenv > /dev/null

}
echo "after getora"
```

After executing foo.sh I get:

```
>./foo.sh validsid
start
b4 getora
after getora
```

So I can tell that there is no problem in simply calling the ksh script since the echo commands for "b4 getora" and "after getora" work. But there is some issue with executing the function since I don't get echo "1" or echo "2" which I would expect.

Furthermore, If I run foo.sh as a ksh script, everything works fine.

Therefore, I can assume that there is some sort of difference in syntax between the two languages that i am not catching. Can anyone assist?

**UPDATE:**
I added `set -x` at the top of my full ksh script, (what I included in my question is just a subset). I found that the script hung at a point later in my script that the function I posted:

```
++ echo

++ grep -v '#'
++ read VAR VALUE
(hanging here)
```

Those code for this part of the script is:

```
echo $GLOBPARFIL
grep -v "#" ${GLOBPARFIL}|while read VAR VALUE
do
        export ${VAR}=${VALUE}
done
```

So `$GLOBPARFIL` doesn't get set properly. It also happens to be a variable that gets pulled in and set from `getoravariables ()`. Output from debugging tat demonstrates this:

```
++ read VAR VALUE
++ export GLOBPARFIL=/home/local/par/global.par
++ GLOBPARFIL=/home/local/par/global.par
```

This lines up with @jlliagre answer below that declares that the the variables are not getting properly set. However, I tried the workaround with only the same undesirable result.

**UPDATE 2:**

Following the information and logic provided I was able to find the true source and create a workaround:

PROBLEM:

```
grep -v "#" ${file_location}| tr "^" " " | while read VAR VALUE
```

SOLUTION:

```
while read VAR VALUE

do

        export ${VAR}=${VALUE}
done <<%
$(grep -v "#" ${file_location}| tr "^" " ")
%
```

I will mark as complete. But if I could receive more information on why exactly this workaround solves the problem I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sourcing a file ignores the shebang so the fact it refers to `ksh` doesn't prevent `bash` to process it.

The issue is with that line:

```
grep -w ${1} ${ORATAB_LOC} | grep -v "#" | sed "s/:/ /g" | read SID ORAHOME ASK
```

Under `ksh`, the last component of a pipeline is run by the main shell while under bash, it is run by a subshell. The variables `SID,` `ORAHOME` and `ASK` are then lost just after being set under `bash`.

Here is a workaround:

```
read SID ORAHOME ASK <<%
$(grep -w ${1} ${ORATAB_LOC} | grep -v "#" | sed "s/:/ /g")
%
```

Edit:

For the second issue, you might use:

```
while read VAR VALUE
do
        export ${VAR}=${VALUE}
done <<%
$(grep -v # "${GLOBPARFIL}")
%
```

If `GLOBPARFIL` is set, the variables would be correctly set and exported and if `GLOBPARFIL` is unset, which is likely an issue, that would at least not hang the script.

Explanation:

When you run a shell command pipeline, e.g. `command1 | command2 | command3`, the `bash` interpreter is running every command in a subshell. That means any variable setting done in one of the pipeline commands is lost. In your script, you have several `command 1 | read variable1 variable2` idioms. This works with `ksh` which run the `read` instruction in the current shell but not with `bash`.

A portable workaround is to reverse the order of commands by reading the variable at the beginning of the line, and use a [`here document`](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html) to set read standard input. A here document is delimited by any custom string and a common one is `%`. A here document normally contains the standard input itself as plain text. Here we want this input to be the result of the commands that were preceding the `set` instruction in the pipeline so [command substitution](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/commandsub.html) (`$(command)`) is used. This is putting `command` output in the here document.

You might also have used [process substitution](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html):

```
read SID ORAHOME ASK < <(grep -w ${1} ${ORATAB_LOC} | grep -v "#" | sed "s/:/ /g")
```

...

```
while read VAR VALUE
do
        export ${VAR}=${VALUE}
done < <(grep -v "#" "${GLOBPARFIL}")
```

Comment: Thank you, my example bar.ksh script is actually a subset of a larger script of mine. Your answer made me question if my real bar.ksh was making it all the way to the end. I put in an echo at the end of it and it did not return. The issue must be elsewhere, I will have to work more to find the source.

Comment: @exit_1 To debug shell scripts, put `set -x` at the beginning. It will then display all the lines as it executes them.

Comment: Yes, or just run `bash -x foo.sh`.

Comment: Syntactically, the shown `ksh` script is valid `bash`. Semantically, `bash` interprets it differently, namely in the line running `read` as the last component of a pipeline.

Comment: @chepner Good catch, I missed that issue. The variables are indeed not set under `bash`.

Comment: thank you @jlliagre and chepner, please see my update.

Comment: @jlliagre, I believe I might have identified  a similar grep/read operation which is the source of the problem. I'd hate to just show you my code and ask for one of your workarounds. Could you explain your fix more so that I can apply it in future code? Or maybe perhaps link to a doc? For example, what is `%` doing here? and why do we need a `$` before our grep?

Comment: @jlliagre, I played around and found the fix, please see my update. Thank you for your time and effort.

Comment: small followup question, if you don't mind. If this .ksh script is already being used by many other scripts, and I push these changes to production, will the current scripts that use this experience any adverse effects? The rest of our scripts use sh and ksh. Is it possible to know for certain?

Comment: The first approach (here documents) should work with all versions of `ksh` and `bash`. The process substitution method might not be supported by old `ksh` (`ksh88`) implementations.

Answer (score 0):

The most likely scenario is that the function name 'getoravariables' was used to define a second function (which doesn't do anything visible) inside one of the scripts that is not listed here.
Try to grep for 'getoravariables' in all your files, maybe you find it.

Answer (score 0):

I've got a script like this to "force" bash execution of a script.

```
#!/bin/sh
#

if [ "$(ps -p "$$" -o comm=)" != "bash" ]; then
    exec /usr/local/bin/bash "$0" "$@@"
    exit 255
fi
echo blah...
```

I assume that you could use something like this to force ksh execution.  The `ps` options are POSIX, so they should be portable-ish.

p.s.  If there's a better way to do this, please post it.  I'm not proud.